# Am I correct with these problems for Big-O, Big-Theta, Big-Omega or neither?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, trigonometry, algorithms, exponential-function

These are the problems:

1. $x^{x^2}$ and $ 2^{2^x}$
2. $\cos(x)$ and $\tan(x)$
3. $x^3$ and $x$

My answers are:

1. $x^{x^2}$ is O($ 2^{2^x} $)
2. Neither Big O, nor Big Omega, nor Big Theta
3. $x^3$ is Big-Omega($x$)

Are these correct answers?

Comment: Hint for 2: $-1 \leq \cos(x) \leq 1$.

Comment: Does that mean my answer is wrong? I thought it was neither because at each quadrant of the unit circle, the signs flipped, so there was no way to represent it as Big O or Big Omega

Comment: @Team.Coco Your answers are correct (assuming we're looking at the behaviour as $x\to +\infty$, things would be different for $x \to 0$).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Here's a table, showing the general idea:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cZTUp.png)

1.lim x^{x^2}/2^{2^x}
the limit is 0
because x^{x^2}/2^{2^x} = x^2 log x / 4^x => x^3/4^x so x^{x^2} is o(2^{2^x}) bucuase exponential functions grows faster than polynomials

2.lim cos(x)/tan(x) for this lim 1/sin(x) and lim sin(x) doesn't exist and
we want x→∞ so this Periodic function doesn't have a big O notation .

3.for lim x^3/x we have infinity so x^3 is small omega (x) and  () = (()) ⇒ () = Ω(), because Big Omega is used to indicate that  ≥

Comment: Ad 1., we have $$\lim_{x\to +\infty} \frac{x^{x^2}}{2^{2^x}} = 0.$$ Ad 2., $\frac{\cos x}{\tan x} = \frac{\cos^2 x}{\sin x}$.

Comment: @daniel fischer yes i'm sorry in number (1) your answer is corect . i try to edit my answer sorry